# Is there a minimum number of values needed for facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to use facet_wrap and is doesn't always been displayed.

I've created a reproducible example what generate information for class scores per subject.
In the first example I can tell that it's working just fine,
And I can see the violin for each subject (Math, Reading and Writing),
But with the sample second example, nothing been displayed for the "Math" subject.

The only change I did between the first and second example is to remove one "Math" observation per class from the data.
Maybe there is minimum number of values need in order to display the graph?
Is that the reason? can I bypass this limitation? (I don't want to create false info, I would like to use the info as is).

Also, with the second example I'm getting the following warning, maybe it will help:

> In max(data$density) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

```
info <- data.frame("Class" = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
                                   "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
                                   "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C",
                                   "D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D"), 
                    "Subject" = c("Math","Math","Math","Reading","Reading","Reading","Writing","Writing","Writing",
                                  "Math","Math","Math","Reading","Reading","Reading","Writing","Writing","Writing",
                                  "Math","Math","Math","Reading","Reading","Reading","Writing","Writing","Writing",
                                  "Math","Math","Math","Reading","Reading","Reading","Writing","Writing","Writing"),
                        "Score" = c(round(runif(36,0,100))))

library("ggplot2")
ggplot(data = info, aes(x = Class, y = Score)) + 
  geom_violin(trim = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~Subject)

# Same as info, just one less "Math" observation per class
infoLess <- data.frame("Class" = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
                                   "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
                                   "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C",
                                   "D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D"), 
                   "Subject" = c("Math","Math","Reading","Reading","Reading","Writing","Writing","Writing",
                                 "Math","Math","Reading","Reading","Reading","Writing","Writing","Writing",
                                 "Math","Math","Reading","Reading","Reading","Writing","Writing","Writing",
                                 "Math","Math","Reading","Reading","Reading","Writing","Writing","Writing"),
                   "Score" = c(round(runif(32,0,100))))

ggplot(data = infoLess, aes(x = Class, y = Score)) + 
  geom_violin(trim = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~Subject)
```

Result of the first plot

[image: Result of the first plot]

Result of the second plot

[image: Result of the second plot]

Comment: `facet_wrap` doesn't have a minimum, but `geom_violin` does, 3 points apparently.

Comment: With < 10 points, I'd recommend just plotting the data, perhaps jittered. Estimating a density with so few points seems borderline misleading.